# How to type json files as tsconfig.json and package.json

Tags: json, typescript, schema, typed

I noticed that some json files with specific names get intellisense, like:

1. `tsconfig.json`
2. `jsconfig.json`
3. `package.json`
4. `.eslintrc.json`
5. `.prettierrc.json`

Some screenchots

[[image]]

[[image]]

how can i type the schema of my own json files is it declares as a json module or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found that the json Schemas are based on the [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/) that would enable intellisense for json files

here is a good intro for defining your own json schema https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/basics.html

here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just create a `person.model.ts` file that carries your json interface then export the interface from the file in which is defined

```
interface Person{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

then import it wherever you want to use it

```
import Person from "./person.model.ts"
```

then use it as a type for your json

```
 let p:Person = {
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 20
}
```

also your editor/IDE will guide you with the missing types and will throw an error if you entered a wrong property like that
[image]

Comment: i don't mean JavaScript JSON literals, i mean json files like config.json, data.json

Comment: oo i misunderstood your question